# Gigabyte GA-P75-D3 Motherboard stuck on the logo screen(s), hot keys do not work

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I have a relatively old machine with GA-P75-D3 Motherboard, SSD and 4 cards of RAM (I think max allowed RAM is there).

Yesterday the computer stopped turning on. When powering up, it displays a big colourful splash screen with UEFI Dual BIOS and a prompt to press DEL / F9 / F12 / END at the bottom. But none of the keys work. Except for the Ctrl+Alt+Del combination, which turns the screen black for 2 seconds, after which the splash screen reappears. That means the keyboard works.
Here's what we've tried:

1. We took out the BIOS battery, switched the computer off and shorted the battery contacts on the board for 5 seconds, and place the battery again on, that didn't help.
2. Pressed POWER with the computer switched off, hold and wait for the computer switched on and switch off again. This does not start BIOS recovery and didn't change anything.
3. Pressed POWER and RESET simultaneously and held down as last point, i.e. until the computer turned on and turned off again. This does not restore BIOS again.

There is no speaker on the board, so I can't figure out the fault code from the sound.

Although once we did manage with some trickery to get the computer to display not a big colourful splash screen, but a small "American Megatrends" logo in the top left corner on a completely black screen (no more lettering) when the computer is turned on. This mode is then switched off by holding down POWER during the on - off cycle.

Please advise what else I could try.

Comment: Disconnect everything. Test Memory -> PSU -> Motherboard is what I would do.

Comment: This is a site about IT in business environment, in which case you simply request another machine and probably send the failed one to the service. But this question is much more appropriate in SuperUser.

Comment: Thank you @NikitaKipriyanov